# Can I star a single attachment in Slack?

Tags: slack

Sometimes I get slack messages (most often from webhooks or bots) that contain several attachments in a single message. Is there a way I can star only one of such attachments without staring the entire message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

Slack is super limited in it's capabilities, I find. In much the same way you can't comment on individual topics that people post, you also don't have the granularity to favorite things other than an entire post.